# Restkit threading sequentially

Tags: ios, multithreading, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm fetching data from a webservice using RestKit (0.20)/ JSON . So far I've got things working for small amounts of data but I need this working for 10.000+ records. As it can take quite a long time to fetch that data (especially over 3G or slower connections) I want to chop it into pieces but I'm getting into trouble with threads. I want to :

1. fetch 1000 records
2. map them into objects
3. push them into a SQLlite database
4. update the progress bar UI
5. if there are more to fetch go to 1 again

My code so far is:

```
- (void) loadPeople {
.. not so relevant code and setup ..

 peoplePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebservice.com/api/v2/people?columns=id,first_name,last_name&sort=updated_at&limit=1000&offeset=%d",offset];
 NSURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path: peoplePath parameters:nil];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        [Person savePeople:mappingResult.array];
        [self updatePeopleProgressBar];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog (@"Error: %@", error);
         NSLog (@"Response:  %@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
     }];
    [operation start];
}
```

The part starting at peoplePath should be executed again and again (incrementing the offset variable by 1000), but I'm clueless on where to implement the loop. 
However it should ONLY execute the next iteration after the current save and update is finished: I'm keeping track on how many have been saved, in case the user quits the app, so I can resume next time. So I would need some kind of sequential threading...

I guess the problem lies into my limeted knowledge of blocks and multithreading. Anyone who can give me a clue on how to do this.

Updated method:

```
- (void) loadPeople : (NSInteger) offset {
    NSString *apiKey = self.APIKey;

    NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKMapping *mapping = [Mappings peopleMapping];
    NSString *pathPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/people",basePathPattern];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:pathPattern
                                                                                           keyPath:keyPath
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/%@",[self clientURLPart],basePathPattern]];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-API-KEY" value:apiKey];

    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Content-type application" value:@"json" ];
    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Accept application" value:@"json"];


    NSString *peoplePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@?columns=id,first_name,last_name&sort=updated_at&limit=4&offset=%d",[self clientURLPart],basePathPattern,offset];

    NSURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:peoplePath parameters:nil];


    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        [Person savePeople:mappingResult.array];
        NSLog(@"Foundrecords %d",[mappingResult.array count]);
        if ([mappingResult.array count] == 4) {
            [self loadPeople:(offset + 4)];
        }

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog (@"Error: %@", error);
         NSLog (@"Response:  %@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
     }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show should be in a method which takes a page number or offset number. Then, in the success block you can call the method (kind of recursively) to start the next download with appropriate information from the 'current' download. This avoids all threading related issues.

Comment: Great idea, should have mentioned I already tried that but got an error. Thought it was Restkit not liking this. I basicly had my method defined as: - (void) loadPeople : (NSInteger) offset { and then later on: [Person savePeople:mappingResult.array];
 if ([mappingResult.array count] == 1000) {
            [self loadPeople:(offset + 1000)];
        } the first pass goes thought, the second time I get a 401 error: invalid API key (while I'm using exactly the same API). Trying to this in Google Chrome using Postman works...

Comment: And your API key is specified where?

Comment: In the same class, currently a method return just the string. - (NSString *) APIKey {
    
    return @"xxxxxx"; }

Comment: I updated the original question with the complete method, so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Rather wasteful to recreate everything. Use Charles to check what is sent. You need to verify the API key, it should be unrelated to RestKit or the recursive call...